# Equivalent of the English "Rise and shine!"

Tags: english-to-german

Several sites that I've consulted propose different phrases for the English exhortation "Rise and shine!"

Suggested equivalents are the very literal, "Steh auf und scheine!" as well as, "Raus aus den Federn!" (something about feathers?).

Is either of these in common use today? If not, what is the true equivalent?

Comment: "Raus aus den Federn" means something like "Get up now". The feather part comes from   bedcovers, which were filled with feathers in the past and some use it still today. I've often heard "Raus aus den Federn", but never in my life have I heard the other one "Steh auf und scheine",

Answer (score 1):

I asked Urban Dictionary what “rise and shine” means in English, and they say it's about calling someone to wake up. And that is indeed

> Raus aus den Federn!

in German. As we all have feather pillows and duvets for our beds.

And no, you won't get any of the sexual innuendos from UD with this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't have the same connotations, but it's probably as close as you can get. "Rise and shine" creates an analogy between the sleeper and the sun; the sun rises in the morning and then shines all day, and expression hints that the sleeper will do something similar. Also "shine" can be interpreted as "smile" because your teeth are on display. So there's an implication that you're going to wake up happy and ready for something important. The expression actually isn't all that common, with the more neutral "wake up" or "get out of bed" being more frequent.

Comment: PS. There may be a connection between this expression and a passage in the King James Bible: "Arise, shine; for thy light is come, and the glory of the LORD is risen upon thee." (Isaiah 60 verse 1.) In the Luther Bible this is "Mache dich auf, werde licht, denn dein Licht kommt und die Herrlichkeit des Herrn gehet auf über dir. (Jesaja 60:1) (Apologies if there are transcription errors; I couldn't find text that doesn't use black letter and I don't have a lot of practice reading it.)